# Selenium calling class elements doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to push a button on a soccer bookmaker's web page using Selenium's Chromedriver. My problem is that nothing happens when I call Selenium's `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('c-events__item c-events__item_col')`.

**Fixed:**

I was trying to get the info from: a class names `'c-events__more c-events__more_bets js-showMoreBets'`.

using `find_by_class_name()` cannot handle spaces as it will think its compound classes, instead I used csselector and it works like a charm now. 
`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.c-events__item.c-events__item_col')`

Comment: Please share what error you get when you execute the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you that you can't use multiple classes within `find_elements_by_class_name`. You can only use one class at a time. Since the method returns a selenium object, you could just chain the method three times, but the better thing to do is to just use the css selector method.

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

You should use a different method. If you want to select based on multiple classes, I recommend using the `find_elements_by_css_selector` method on the driver object. The dots before the class names make what is called a class selector. You can read more about selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.c-events__more .c-events__more_bets .js-showMoreBets')
```

Since you're hitting an anchor tag, you might want to add the `a` to the selector as well. E.g.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.c-events__more .c-events__more_bets .js-showMoreBets a')
```

This is always my goto page for using python selenium. Here are all of the methods available for use -> http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

using find_by_class_name() cannot handle spaces as it will think its compound classes, instead I used csselector and it works like a charm now. driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.c-events__item.c-events__item_col')

Comment: that's what I said? If I helped answer your question, may you mark my answer as correct?